# If list contains more than 25 elements, take only the newest 25 elements at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `messages` representing a `[]` with multiple messages. I would like to set a lock so that only the 25 most recent messages are available. I iterate over the `messages` in the `MessageSide` component. But with the function `updateMessage(...)` I can't access `messages.length` which is always 1, so I wrote this in a `useEffect`. Now to my question how can I always best display only the 25 newest elements, that is, delete the oldest elements first.

```
    const Messages = (roomId) => {
      const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(messages.length)
      }, [messages]);
    
    
      const updateMessages = (message) => {
        if (roomId.toString() === message.roomid) {
          const incomingMessage = {
            ...message,
            id: message.senderId,
            timestamp: message.timestamp,
            chatid: message.roomid
          };
          console.log(messages.length) // always 1 
          setMessages((messages) => [...messages, incomingMessage]);
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem("frankenstein_unread_messages", 3);
        }
      };
};

export default Messages;
```

MessageSide

```
function MessageSide(props) {
  const { messages, } = Messages(1);

  return (
          <div className="item">
            {messages.map((message) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Message
                    message={message.body} // Einzelenen Nachrichten text
                    id={message.id} // User-ID id-profile
                    timestamp={message.timestamp} // writtenDate
                    chatid={message.chatid}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div ref={messagesEndRef}/>
  );
}

export default MessageSide;
```

The messages data:

How it looks like in the console

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-05-23T08:56:01.075Z", body: "Hello"}
1: {id: 1, id_profile: 1, id_groupchat: 3, timestamp: "2021-05-23T08:56:01.868Z", body: ""}
```

How it is

```
[
   {
     id: 1, // is another id
     id_profile: 1, 
     id_groupchat: 3,
     timestamp: "2021-05-23T08:56:01.075Z",
     body: "Hello"
   },
   {
     id: 1, // is another id
     id_profile: 1, 
     id_groupchat: 3,
     timestamp: "2021-05-23T08:56:01.075Z",
     body: "Test"
   }

]
```

Comment: do you have some data? is the data sorted? what is newest?

Comment: @NinaScholz just a moment, please

Comment: @NinaScholz I updated my question. As you can see the list is sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with a negative value which counts from the end for sorted array.

This approach returns a new array with the wanted count or less if the array is shorter.

```
array.slice(-25)
```